# How to create an analogue of Latex providecommand in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, ghc

Suppose we are importing a module `M` where we expect a function `f1`. But it may not be there. However, we do not want a compilation error, but we want to do something like the following (pseudocode):

```
 import M

 f2 = if (defined f1) then f1 else ...
```

In other words, I would like to make an analogue of Latex `\providecommand` in Haskell:

https://latexref.xyz/_005cprovidecommand.html

Comment: You can work with *template Haskell* for that: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-8.10.2/docs/GHC.html#v:getNamesInScope

Comment: Why do you want this? There may be a better way to accomplish your top-level goal than this. For example, if it is to support multiple versions of a library where the API has changed, use `CPP` and cabal will define appropriate version-checking macros for you.

Comment: @DanielWagner, FYI, those version-checking macros used to be defined by Cabal, but at the urging of yours truly they're now defined by GHC.  Because you need them regardless of build system, and the compiler needs that info to compile the module anyway, so exposing it is basically free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a bad idea.  However, if you really want to do it, @WillemVanOnsem's suggestion will work.

You can create the following separate module to define a Template Haskell (TH) function `provideCommand`.  Note that you have to do this in a separate module from where you want to use `provideCommand` because of a limitation known as the TH "stage restriction", where TH functions can't be used (technically, can't be "spliced") in the same module where they're defined.

```
module ProvideCommand where

import Language.Haskell.TH

provideCommand :: String -> Q [Dec] -> Q [Dec]
provideCommand nam defn = do
  mval <- lookupValueName nam
  case mval of
    Just _ -> return []
    Nothing -> defn
```

This function uses `lookupValueName` to look up a given name at compile time.  If the name is not found, it outputs some provided declarations.

You'd use it like so in some other module.  You need to turn on the `TemplateHaskell` extension to call (i.e., "splice") `provideCommand`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import M
import ProvideCommand

provideCommand "double" [d| double x = x * 2 |]

main = print (double 15)
```

If the name `double` is not already defined (e.g., in module `M`), this will define it by outputting the declarations in the quasiquote `[d| ... |]`.  You can include multiple declarations, include for things other than `double`, but obviously they won't be available unless the `provideCommand` is triggered:

```
provideCommand "double"
  [d| double :: Int -> Int
      double 0 = 0
      double n = addTwo (double (n-1))

      addTwo :: Int -> Int
      addTwo x = x + 2
  |]
```